# Custom shortcode always appears at top of content

Tags: php, wordpress, function, shortcode

I have created a custom shortcode and can get the information to output, however it does not show up where I have placed it in the content hierarchy - it always prints at the top of the post/page. Any clue as to why this may be happening?

in my functions.php:

```
function sc_pdf($atts, $content = null) {
   $pdfname = the_field('pdf_title');
   $pdfimage = the_field('pdf_file');
   $pdflink = the_field('pdf_thumbnail');
   return '<p>'.$pdfname.'</p><p>'.$pdfimage.'</p><p>'.$pdflink.'</p>';
}
add_shortcode("peedeef", "sc_pdf");
```

Comment: Please add the HTML output that demonstrates where the output is actually placed.

Comment: **Note to mods**: this question *may* be a better fit for WPSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the_field method, I assume you use ACF plugin.

You should use `get_field` instead of `the_field` since `the_field` will output the specified field.

```
function sc_pdf($atts, $content = null) {
   $pdfname = get_field('pdf_title');
   ... etc
```

Comment: I have updated the original code to reflect your suggestion, @soju.

Comment: Except: with that edit, later viewers will not see the problematic code, but rather only the *corrected* code - and thus, won't understand the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Always use "return" instead echo.

You'll able to get data in proper location.

Answer (score 2):

***To move your shortcode around, don't use echo.***
if you place the shortcode in your doc in the first example it will always float to the top.
in the second if I place it at the bottom it will appear at the bottom.

My shortcode is [showpod]

**CODE THAT YOU CANT PLACE ANYWHERE**

```
function makepod($atts) {
echo "<div class='podmysqlarray2 showpodholder'><h3 class='widget-title newposts'>Latest Snippets</h3>";
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '6' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
echo '<div class="pod"><li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> </div>';
}
echo "</div>";
}
add_shortcode('showpod', 'makepod');
```

**AND NOW REVISED CODE YOU CAN PLACE ANYWHERE: -**

```
function makepod($atts) {
$cat = "<div class='podmysqlarray2 showpodholder'><h3 class='widget-title newposts'>Latest Snippets</h3>";
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '6' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
$cat.= '<div class="pod"><li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> </div>';
}
$cat .= "</div>";
return $cat;
}
add_shortcode('showpod', 'makepod');
```